# tidyr::complete() doesn't seem to accept dat as a variable name

Tags: r, tidyr

```
complete(data=tibble(dat=c(1, 3)), dat=full_seq(x=dat, period=1))
```

gives the error:

```
Error in full_seq(x = dat, period = 1) : object 'dat' not found
```

If I change all three occurrences of `dat` into any other name, everything works as expected. For instance (renaming dat to xat):

```
complete(data=tibble(xat=c(1, 3)), xat=full_seq(x=xat, period=1))
```

gives the expected result (completed with the missing 2):

```
    xat
  <dbl>
1    1.
2    2.
3    3.
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include sample data and your expected outcome. I'm unsure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: re-edit: added a working case and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This works, although it is useless:

```
df <- tibble(dat = 1:3)
complete(df, dat)
```